# Reshaping a MultiVector in Trilinos

Tags: parallel-computing, mpi, trilinos

I'm using Trilinos for a problem and I have an `Epetra_MultiVector` object with 1 vector of length `m*n*nFrames`. I need to turn it into an `Epetra_MultiVector` object with `nFrames` of length `m*n`. The first `m*n` entries need to go into the first vector, the second into the second vector and so on.

I have this working fine with just one process. What I'm doing is extracting all the data to a standard C++ array on process 0, reshaping that into a 2D standard C++ array (an array of pointers actually), and then creating a new `Epetra_MultiVector` with my 2D array.

With more than one process, however, because everything is on process 0, when I create the new `Epetra_MultiVector`, all the data for the other process is nonsense (accessing undefined memory, I guess).

So my question ultimately is: how do I reshape a Trilinos `Epetra_MultiVector` correctly with more than one process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a function that does it. It does not do it in place, and is not particularly well written, but for posterity I'll add my solution. I realize that I really don't need to reshape the standard C++ array, but I'll leave it there until it becomes a problem for me.

```
int ReshapeMultiVector(Epetra_MultiVector *&reshapedMultiVec, const int length, const int numVecs, const Epetra_MultiVector &originalMultiVec, Epetra_MpiComm &comm){

    /* Function to reshape a multivector. Does it by copying the values, so additional memory will be required.
     * Note that this function does NOT delete the original vector.
     * INPUTS
     *  reshapedMultiVec - This is a reference to a null pointer that will point to the
     *             new (reshaped) multivector.
     *  length       - Global length of the new multivector
     *  numVecs      - The number of vectors in the new multivector.
     *  originalMultiVec - The original multivector that is being reshaped.
     *  comm         - MPI communicator
     * OUTPUT
     *  int      - Error flag
     */

    int err;

    int numVecsOrig = originalMultiVec.NumVectors();
    int lengthOrig = originalMultiVec.GlobalLength();

    //extract phase_gradx and phase_grady as standard arrays so that we can reshape them.
    double** originalMultiVec_std = new double*[numVecsOrig];
    for(int i=0;i<numVecsOrig;++i){
        originalMultiVec_std[i] = new double[lengthOrig];
    }
    err = MultiVectorToArray(originalMultiVec_std, originalMultiVec, false);
    if(err) return err;

    // Copy the values to all the processors after extracting them.
    for(int i=0;i<numVecsOrig;++i){
        comm.Broadcast(originalMultiVec_std[i], lengthOrig, 0);
    }


    double** reshaped_std = new double*[numVecs];
    for(int i=0;i<numVecs;++i){
        reshaped_std[i] = new double[length];
    }
    err = Reshape2DArray(originalMultiVec_std, lengthOrig, numVecsOrig, reshaped_std, length, numVecs);
    if(err) return err;


    Epetra_Map reshapedMap(length,0,comm);

    //Initialize the vector
    int numMyElements = reshapedMap.NumMyElements();
    int* myGlobalElements = reshapedMap.MyGlobalElements(); 


    reshapedMultiVec = new Epetra_MultiVector(reshapedMap,numVecs);
    double ** Ap = reshapedMultiVec->Pointers();

    for (int j=0; j<numVecs; ++j)
    {
        double * v = Ap[j];

        // Fill it
        for (int i=0; i<numMyElements; ++i)
        {
            v[i] = reshaped_std[j][myGlobalElements[i]];
        }
    }


    // free memory
    for(int i=0;i<numVecsOrig;++i){
        delete[] originalMultiVec_std[i];
    }
    delete[] originalMultiVec_std;
    for(int i=0;i<numVecs;++i){
        delete[] reshaped_std[i];
    }
    delete[] reshaped_std;


    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reshaping arrays is something that's a bit Matlab-specific -- most other environments (including Trilinos, PETSc, ...) allow you to create a vector or matrix but not let you re-interpret it as something else. You need to copy the elements by hand into a matrix of different size.